# Wrong class type reference in docstring type hint

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Filesystem tree of my project:

- `first_package`

  - `__init__.py`
  - `first.py`
- `second_package`

  - `__init__.py`
  - `second.py`
- `main.py`

`first.py` contains:

```
class Product:
    pass
```

`second.py` contains:

```
class Product:
    pass
```

In the main file, I want to create a function and point the type hint to both Product     classes from different modules:

```
from first_package.first import Product
from second_package.second import Product as SecondProduct


def test(a: Product, b: SecondProduct):
    pass
```

The function documentation (ctrl+q) generates links to Product classes, however they both lead to the first module when clicked.

```
main 
def test(a: Product,
         b: Product) -> None
```

*here I clicked on the type link of the argument b*

```
first_package.first 
class Product
```

I also tried import `from second_package import second`, specifying `second.Product` for argument b, but that didn't change anything.

Can you tell me how to avoid this?

Comment: Reproduced in Pycharm 2021.3. Clearly a bug and should be [reported](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/reporting-issues.html).